# Parsing a string array from a JSON file into global variable, but when using it the array content is null

Tags: java, android, json, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have a JSON file with different Strings I want to create an altert dialog, but my String array is not working

I created a private String category. Into the category String I parse my String values with a for loop, in the method getJobArray. There the LogCat output tells me that the array gets filled with the String values. However, when I use the category String array in the onCreateDialog it tells me that the values are all null. I cannot even print the length to the LogCat

```
public class MultipleChoiceDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private RequestQueue mRQ;
    private Context mContext;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQ;
    private static String TAG = "xd";
    private String[] category;


    public interface onMultiChoiceListener{
        void onPositiveClicked(String[] list,ArrayList<String> selectedItemList);
        void onNegativeButtonClicked();
    }

    onMultiChoiceListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        mRequestQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        getJobArray();

        try {
            mListener = (onMultiChoiceListener) context;
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw  new ClassCastException(getActivity() + "onMultiChoice not working error");
        }
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final ArrayList<String> selectedItemList = new ArrayList<>();



        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());



        //not working don't understand why... here category is null
        final String[] list = category;

        builder.setTitle("Select one")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(list, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean b) {
                        if(b){
                            selectedItemList.add(list[i]);
                        }else{
                            selectedItemList.remove(list[i]);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        mListener.onPositiveClicked(list,selectedItemList);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        mListener.onNegativeButtonClicked();
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }



    private void getJobArray(){
        //todo here I can get array from json array

        String url = "http://api_staging.jab.poweredby.cnddts.at/mobile/metadata/categories?portal=1";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("categories");

                            category = new String[jsonArray.length()];

                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: is getting array ready right now");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: jsonArray length" + jsonArray.length());
                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject categories = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                category[i] = categories.getString("name");

                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: array input " + category[i]);

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: catch caught...");
                        }

                    }
                }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQ.add(request);
    }
}
```

JSON sample:

```
{ 
    "categories": [ 
    { 
        "uid": "1", 
        "name": "Arbeitsrecht/Sozialrecht" 
    },{ 
        "uid": "2", 
        "name": "Bankrecht/Kapitalmarktrecht"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show use a sample of json?

Comment: @KunLun Yes there is a small part of my Json:

 {
    "categories": [
        {
            "uid": "1",
            "name": "Arbeitsrecht/Sozialrecht"
        },
        {
            "uid": "2",
            "name": "Bankrecht/Kapitalmarktrecht"

Comment: @KunLun

Here is the LogCat output that when looping trough the array gets generated correctly...

2019-08-30 11:28:11.991 14065-14065/com.example.candidatisapp D/xd: onResponse: jsonArray length30
array input Gesellschaftsrecht/Corporate/M&A
array input Immaterialgüterrecht/Wettbewerbsrecht

Comment: seems like a classic case of expecting async work to be done immediately. You should fetch the data first, wait for it to be fetched, then show it.

Comment: @TimCastelijns how can I fetch first?

Comment: The issue is related to using category before is it being initialized after the API call. I have added the detail of it below.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the reason of this is that the API calling in `onAttach(Context context)` method. So when you are calling the API then category has not initialized and the `onCreateDialog()` will have null value because API will call happens out of main thread and main thread will not wait for the API response.

By the way, calling an API all then time when dialog will be called is not a good idea. API calling should be optimized with a minimum number of call for the better app performance. So, a good solution will be to call the API before the dialog called in Activity or Fragement may be. And When the dialog will be called then use the json value directly from the response data.

Comment: I hope it will be the accpeted answer if it has fulfilled your requirement.